# Asio handler of async operations are not called while their sync counterparts work fine

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing some networking code based on ASIO (standalone, without boost). I've written some test code with synchronous workflow which works as expected. But when I try to go async (basically replacing `asio::read_until` with `asio::async_read_until`) the completion handler is never called:

```
auto receive = [&](auto self)
{
    asio::async_read_until(socket, buf, '\n', [&](auto const& err, auto read)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::getline(is, s);
        std::cout << "received: \"" << s << "\"\n\n";

        if (socket.is_open())
            self(self);
    });
};
```

`socket` is a `tcp::socket` and `buf` a `asio::streambuf`. This is the only part in my code that has changed and I don't know why the handler isn't called here.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <asio.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

using namespace asio::ip;
using namespace std::literals;

constexpr auto IP = "127.0.0.1"sv;
constexpr auto Service = "50000"sv;
constexpr unsigned short Port = 50000;

void server()
{
    asio::io_context context;
    std::thread t([&context] { context.run(); });

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), Port));
    auto socket = acceptor.accept();

    std::cout << "Server connected.\n";

    asio::streambuf buf;
    auto receive = [&](auto self)
    {
        asio::async_read_until(socket, buf, '\n', [&](auto const& err, auto read)
        {
            std::string s;
            std::istream is(&buf);
            std::getline(is, s);
            std::cout << "received: \"" << s << "\"\n\n";

            if (socket.is_open())
                self(self);
        });
    };

    receive(receive);;

    while (socket.is_open())
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::cout << "Server shutdown.\n";
    context.stop();
    t.join();
}

void client()
{
    asio::io_context context;
    std::thread t([&context] { context.run(); });

    auto endpoints = tcp::resolver(context).resolve(IP, Service);

    tcp::socket socket(context);
    asio::connect(socket, endpoints);

    std::cout << "Client connected.\n";

    std::string msg;
    asio::streambuf buf;
    std::getline(std::cin, msg);

    while (!msg.empty())
    {
        std::ostream os(&buf);
        os << msg << "\n";

        auto written = asio::write(socket, buf);
        if (written != msg.size() + 1)
            std::cout << "Couldn't send message.";

        std::getline(std::cin, msg);
    }

    context.stop();
    t.join();
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t1(server);
    std::thread t2(client);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit

It looks like no async operations are working for me. If I make the acceptor async aswell its handler never gets called (despite the client beeing able to connect to a socket).

Those are the changes made (inside the `server()` function):

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), Port));
acceptor.async_accept([&](auto const& err, tcp::socket sock)
{
    socket = std::move(sock);
    cv.notify_one();
});

{
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk);
}
```

I've set a break point inside the lambda to be sure, but it hasn't been triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: `run` ends when there are not any pending tasks to be performed. In your case `run` was started before first async task was initated. `run` finished and handler could not be invoked. Solution? Use `work` object, it prevents `run` from ending when there are not any tasks.

```
asio::io_context context;
asio::io_context::work work{context};
std::thread t([&context] { context.run(); });
```

Because `work` was deprecated, you can use `executor_work_guard`:

```
asio::executor_work_guard<decltype(context.get_executor())> work{context.get_executor()};
```

or in shorter form only if you are using c++17:

```
asio::executor_work_guard work{context.get_executor()};
```

But there is one issue with this approach, `t.join` will wait forever. `work` must be destroyed so that `run` could end. We cannot achive this behaviour with local variable.

But using smart pointer we can do:

```
std::unique_ptr< asio::io_context::work> work = 
        std::make_unique< asio::io_context::work>(context);
std::thread t([&context] { context.run(); });
... the rest code
context.stop();
work.reset();
t.join();
```

---

The second problem is in lambda:

```
auto receive = [&](auto self)
{
    asio::async_read_until(socket, buf, '\n', [&](auto const& err, auto read)
    {                                         ^^^^
        std::string s;
        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::getline(is, s);
        std::cout << "received: \"" << s << "\"\n\n";

        if (socket.is_open())
            self(self);
    });
};
```

you are capturing `self` by `[&]` reference, it is bad idea because `self` is local inside outer lambda. Because *async-function* returns immediately, `self` is destroyed and inside inner lambda you have dangling reference.
Try this:

```
[self,&socket,&buf](auto const& err, auto read)
```

Comment: That did the job, thank you! Good catch on the lambda part. Overlooked that when writing the example, the production code looks better I promise :).